# Declaring concrete method in abstract class

Tags: java, abstract, overriding, abstract-methods

I need to override `toString()` method for all of the concrete method of my abstract class - exactly the same in all cases. So here is what I *want* to do (`SomeEnum` is a separate class which has just an enum declaration):

**abstract class**

```
public abstract class ClassA {
    protected SomeEnum name;
    protected int some_int;

// Constructor here

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name.toString().toLowerCase() + " > " + Integer.toString(some_int);
}
}
```

**concrete class (example)**

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    private static final int some_const = 1;
    private SomeEnum name = SomeEnum.ENUM_1;

public ClassB(int some_int) {
    super(some_const, some_int);
}
}
```

For some reason **I cannot do it that way without runtime exceptions** and I need to declare abstract method in the abstract class and then provide (exactly the same) implementation of `toString()` in every of the concrete classes implementations.

What is wrong with this approach?

**EDIT:** The exception I get is `NullPointerException` that then points me to `ClassA.toString()`.

Comment: We can't tell, without knowing what compiler errors you're getting. Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem, and include the compiler error.

Comment: It looks odd that you've shadowed the `name` field in your subclass. Is that intentional?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll provide more details shortly.

Comment: @Duncan It's intentional but if its unnecessary, let me know.

Comment: Well, see Kevin's answer/comment below to see what you could do instead. It's not the cause of your problem, I don't think. But then again, nothing you've described so far should cause compiler errors.

Comment: Ok, so it's *not* a compiler error. It's a runtime exception. Very different thing!

Comment: You're right, I've edited my question.

Comment: For complete clarity, please post the contents of your `ClassA` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring `name` as a field on `ClassB` assign `someEnum` in the constructor of `ClassB` so it uses the field from the supertype.  The supertype does not have access to the `name` field on the subtype, which causes the NPE when `toString` is called.

```
public ClassB(int some_int) {
    super(some_const, some_int);
    this.name = SomeEnum.ENUM_1;
}
```

### Full Example

**ClassB**

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    private static final int some_const = 1;

    public ClassB(int some_int) {
        super(some_const, some_int);
        this.name = SomeEnum.ENUM_1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB b = new ClassB(4);
        b.toString();
    }
}
```

**ClassA**

```
public abstract class ClassA {
    protected SomeEnum name;
    protected int some_int;

    public ClassA(int someConst, int some_int2) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.toString().toLowerCase() + " > "
                + Integer.toString(some_int);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is a valid point to make (perhaps as a comment?), but I don't believe *not* doing this would cause compiler errors.

Comment: @DuncanJones The code in the OP throws a NPE since the field `name` is null in the abstract class and the supertype cannot reference the `name` field which is assigned in the subtype.

Comment: The joy of truly understanding what the OP wants! Looks like your answer is correct, good spot!

Comment: @DuncanJones I keep my IDE open when Stacking, it pays!  Thanks!